# Why does the balance become 1.00 whenever the sql command below is executed no matter what value of $cost is?

Tags: mysql, decimal

Why does the balance become 1.00 whenever the sql command below is executed no matter what value of $cost is?

```
update account set balance=balance-'$cost' and username='steven'"
```

The value of  balance is bigger than $cost initially, after the execution, the balance of 'steven' becomes 1.00. What's wrong?

Say, when the initial balance is 2000.00, the $cost is 300, after this subtraction, the balance becomes 1.00.
What's wrong?

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to put in **WHERE** clause:

```
UPDATE account SET balance=balance-'$cost' WHERE username='steven' LIMIT 1;
```

What is happening in your query

```
UPDATE account SET balance=balance-'$cost' AND username='steven';
```

According to [MySQL Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html), the substraction takes place first, which, for the example you gave, will return a positive number:

```
UPDATE account SET balance=(balance-'$cost') AND username='steven';
UPDATE account SET balance=(1700) AND username='steven';
```

Then, the assignment (=) of username to 'steven' takes place, which returns 'steven':

```
UPDATE account SET balance=(1700) AND (username='steven');
UPDATE account SET balance=(1700) AND ('steven');
```

Then, the (AND) boolean operator kicks in, converts both the positive number and the string to boolean values, both TRUE, and then ANDs them, which will return TRUE:

```
UPDATE account SET balance=((1700) AND ('steven'));
UPDATE account SET balance=(TRUE AND TRUE);
UPDATE account SET balance=(TRUE);
```

Finally, since balance is a floating point number, TRUE gets converted into a number, which defaults to to 1.0:

```
UPDATE account SET balance=(TRUE);
UPDATE account SET balance=1;
```

This will affect all records, not just the one for username 'steve'.

Answer (score 0):

The query you are looking for that does what you are trying to do (but is probably still wrong) is:

```
update account set balance=balance-'$cost', username='steven'
```

But probably, you want the following? Or are you really trying to set the balance and username for every row in the table for some reason?

```
UPDATE account SET balance = balance - $cost WHERE username = 'steven'
```

Comment: If nothing happens, then why is something happening? ie, the balance is set to 1. The extra double quote is likely a copy/paste error. No, the reason why it's being set to one is boolean arithmatic. I couldn't tell you exactly what is being evaluated and how, but the `AND` will be executing last and evaluating to `true`, or 1 as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the obvious...

I find it odd that you'd change the username at the same time you update the balance.  Could it be that you meant "... **where** username = 'steven'"?